# Which image processing technique removes swirling(typical low-light imaging artifacts) and creates a clear image?

Tags: image, image-processing

I took this picture

[image: Picture]

Which image processing technique removes the swirling(typical low-light imaging artifacts) and creates a clear image?

Comment: what "swirling"? I don't know what I'm looking at, but I see what looks like typical low-light imaging artifacts. More information about your problem would help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Dai. What you call "typical low-light imaging artifacts" is what I call "swirling"(ie what the effect swirl in some image manipulation programs produces). How would you minimize the "typical low-light imaging artifacts"?

Comment: Typically it would be noise that occurs in low-light photography. The best way to avoid it is to take multiple exposures on a tripod and average them. Median filters are also useful.

Comment: *Nothing* is going to create a clear image if this is all you have to start with. The signal to noise ratio is just too low. The best you can do is to smear the noise, but that will smear image features as well.

Comment: Use a different (lower) ISO setting on your camera...

Answer (score 0):

There is different techniques for filtering out the artifacts from image. Some are based on machine learning and some use the pattern recognition.

I found this method> Optimization based pattern artifact removal from an image .

This is how it works in summary> An input image 'I' is decomposed into a latent natural image 'L' and a pattern artifact image 'E', where I = L + E. Pattern artifacts have unnatural spectrum peaks, and the such kind of peaks are separated into 'E'. 
    This code cannot deal with complex patterns.

Here is the matlab code for the function>

```
function [L, E] = imdecpattern( Y, lambda, tol, nite )
%IMDECPATTERN recovers a degraded image with a pattern artifact
% by decomposing the image into the latent image and the pattern image. 
%
% [L, E] = IMDECPATTERN( Y )
% [L, E] = IMDECPATTERN( Y, lambda, tol, nite )
%
% arguments
% Y : input image
% L : latent image
% E : artifact image
% lambda : decomposition degree (default lambda=3)
% tol    : the tolerance of a constraint Y = L + E (default tolerance=0)
% nite   : the number of iterations to solve the problem.
%
%
%
% This program solves the following equation
%
% min_{l,e}  |Dl|2,1  + lambda |Fe|c,1
% s.t.       | y - (l+e) |2 <= tol,  1'l = 0
%
% where y is an observed image, l is the latent image, e is the artifact image,
% D is differential filtering and F is Fourier transformation.
%
%
% REFERENCE
%
% K. Shirai, S. Ono, and M. Okuda, ``Minimization of mixed norm for frequency
% spectrum of images and its application of pattern noise decomposition,''
% EUSIPCO, 5pages, 2017.
%
%
% parameters
%
if ~exist( 'lambda', 'var' ) || isempty( lambda )
    lambda = 3; % mainly controls decomposition degree
end
if ~exist( 'tol', 'var' ) || isempty( tol )
    tol = 0;    % tolerance of the l2 ball related to noise reduction
end
% for ADMM
if ~exist( 'nite', 'var' ) || isempty( nite )
    nite = 30; % number of iterations
end
rho = 1; % step size
%
% proximity operators
%
% mixed l2,1 norm
% is directly written in the ADMM algorithm
% mixed lc,1 norm
prox_lc1 = @(V,gamma) V.*(1 - gamma./max(gamma,abs(V))); 
% l2 ball projection centered at V with the radius V-Y
prox_l2ball = @(V,V_Y,tol) V + V_Y * (tol/max(tol,norm(V_Y(:)))); % V_Y = V - Y
% which corresponds to ( norm(V_Y(:)) <= tol ) ? ( V ) : ( Y + V_Y*(tol/norm(V_Y(:)) );
[sy,sx,sc] = size( Y );
N = sy*sx; % number of pixels
% % unitary Fourier transform, but the following non-unitary version is faster.
% F = @(X) fft2(X)/sqrt(N);  Ft = @(X) sqrt(N)*ifft2(X);
%
% non-unitary Fourier transform
lambda = sqrt(N) * lambda;
F = @(X) fft2(X);  Ft = @(X) real(ifft2(X));
Zeros = zeros(sy,sx,sc);
Ones = ones(sy,sx,sc);
% initialization of variables
L = Y;  E = Zeros;
% aux variables Z and Lagrangian-multiplier variables U 
Zlh = Zeros;  Ulh = Zeros;
Zlv = Zeros;  Ulv = Zeros;
Ze  = Zeros;  Ue  = Zeros;
Z   = Zeros;  U   = Zeros;
% filters
% circular differential filters
Dh = [0,-1,1];
Dv = [0;-1;1];
% laplacian filter
DhDh_DvDv = [0,-1,0;-1,4,-1;0,-1,0];
% pre-computation of inverse filters
FA11 = 1 + repmat( psf2otf( DhDh_DvDv, [sy,sx] ), [1,1,sc] );
FA22 = 1 + Ones;
FA12 = Ones;
FA21 = Ones;
idetFA = 1./(FA11.*FA22 - FA12.*FA21); % determinant
iFA11 =  FA22 .* idetFA;  iFA12 = -FA12 .* idetFA;
iFA21 = -FA21 .* idetFA;  iFA22 =  FA11 .* idetFA;
% % weighted version
% sigma = 0.5;
% FW = Ones;
% FW = repmat( psf2otf( fspecial( 'gaussian', 2*ceil(3*sigma)+1, sigma ), [sy,sx] ), [1,1,sc] );
% FW = fftshift(FW);
for t = 1:nite

    %
    % solve l and e
    %
    IZU = (Z - U);
    Fbl = fft2( IZU...
        + imfilter( Zlh - Ulh, Dh, 'corr','circular' )...
        + imfilter( Zlv - Ulv, Dv, 'corr','circular' ) );
    Fbe = fft2( IZU + Ft( Ze - Ue ) );
    L = real( ifft2( iFA11.*Fbl + iFA12.*Fbe ) );
    E = real( ifft2( iFA21.*Fbl + iFA22.*Fbe ) );

    %
    % solve z_l and u_l
    %
    Vlh = imfilter( L, Dh, 'conv','circular' ) + Ulh;
    Vlv = imfilter( L, Dv, 'conv','circular' ) + Ulv;

    % prox of l2,1 norm
    Vl_norm = sqrt(Vlh.*Vlh + Vlv.*Vlv);
    Scale = 1 - (1/rho) ./ max(1/rho, Vl_norm);
    Zlh = Vlh .* Scale;
    Zlv = Vlv .* Scale;

    Ulh = Vlh - Zlh; % update u_l
    Ulv = Vlv - Zlv;    

    %
    % solve z_e and u_e
    %
    Ve = F( E ) + Ue;
    gamma = (lambda/rho);
%   gamma = (lambda/rho) * FW; % weighted version
    Ze = prox_lc1( Ve, gamma );

    % the constraint coresponding to mean(e)=0
    Ze(1,1,:) = 0;

    Ue  = Ve  - Ze; % update u_e

    %
    % solve z and u
    %
    V = (L + E) + U;
    dVY = V - Y;
    for c = 1:sc
        Z(:,:,c) = prox_l2ball( Y(:,:,c), dVY(:,:,c), tol );
%       % Actually, this version is faster than the above
%       dVYc = dVY(:,:,c);
%       norm_dVY = norm( dVYc(:) );
%       if ( norm_dVY <= tol )
%           Z(:,:,c) = V(:,:,c);
%       else
%           Z(:,:,c) = Y(:,:,c) + dVY(:,:,c) * (tol/norm_dVY);
%       end
    end
    U = V - Z; % update U
end
end
```

This is the test result>
[image: test result]